# Odoo back date transfer

Tags: odoo

May I ask in odoo 16 is still back-date transfer or stock adjustment.
I think in Odoo 15 stock adjustment, the stock adjust date can be adjusted. But in odoo 16, the stock adjust can only affect current stock.

If not, is it possible to achieve in inventory module.

Thanks